# how to create 3 data points for each column after chunking?

Tags: python, numpy

I have data and tried to split it into another chunks of data

```
data = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1.9], [-3, -2], [1, 1.5], [2.7, 1], [3, 2], [-4, 10], 
[-10, 5], [-6, -10],
             [-11, -2], [-2, -9], [-5, -5], [4, 6.5], [5.7, 6], [7, 2], [-9.5, -10], [10, -5], 
 [-6.4, -1.1]])



def chunk_data(X, chunk_counts=10):
    len_ = len(X)

    half_size = len_ // 2
    first_chunk = [X[: half_size].tolist()]
    rest_data = X[half_size:]
    rest_chunks_n = np.array_split(rest_data, chunk_counts - 1)
    rest_chunks = [arr.tolist() for arr in rest_chunks_n]
    return first_chunk + rest_chunks
                     
X = chunk_data(data, chunk_counts=3)
print(X)
```

I had this as output of the chunked data

```
[[[-1.0, -1.0], [-2.0, -1.9], [-3.0, -2.0], [1.0, 1.5], [2.7, 1.0], [3.0, 2.0], [-4.0, 10.0], [-10.0, 5.0], [-6.0, -10.0]], [[-11.0, -2.0], [-2.0, -9.0], [-5.0, -5.0]], [[4.0, 6.5], [5.7, 6.0], [7.0, 2.0]], [[-9.5, -10.0], [10.0, -5.0], [-6.4, -1.1]]]
```

how to create 2 to 3 data points for each column/ feature of this array out of eavery chunk?

Comment: Could you give an example of how the final output should look like?

Comment: I was thinking a feature or a column must be [[-1.0, -1.0], [-11.0, -2.0], [4.0, 6.5], ....]
second feature would be [[-2.0, -1.9], [5.7, 6.0], [-6.4, -1.1]]
but I'd want to create a set of two points such that size of this set twice the number of features. but without None values and without pandas ..

Comment: I don't think I quite understood the flow of the values..is the following answer any close to what you were looking for?

Comment: if I had this then it would repeat the values
""      ([-3.0, -2.0],)
        ([-3.0, -2.0],)
        ([1.0, 1.5],)
        ([1.0, 1.5],)
        ([2.7, 1.0],)
        ([2.7, 1.0],)
-------------------------
      for lst in zip_longest(*X):
          ls[:2]
what should I do to not repeat them ?

Comment: what is the "zip_longest" in here?

Comment: the columns that I referred to up

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you are trying to re-shape the data like the following (you will have 3 columns, and each row has 3 features/values:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1.9], [-3, -2], [1, 1.5], [2.7, 1], [3, 2], [-4, 10], 
[-10, 5], [-6, -10],[-11, -2], [-2, -9], [-5, -5], [4, 6.5], [5.7, 6], [7, 2], [-9.5, -10], [10, -5],[-6.4, -1.1]])

new_data = np.reshape(data, (12, 3))
print (new_data)
```

[image]

Comment: No I don't want to reshape it because it was 2 D array and I splitt it to chunk  [[[-1.0, -1.0], [-2.0, -1.9], [-3.0, -2.0], [1.0, 1.5], [2.7, 1.0], [3.0, 2.0], [-4.0, 10.0], [-10.0, 5.0], [-6.0, -10.0]], [[-11.0, -2.0], [-2.0, -9.0], [-5.0, -5.0]], [[4.0, 6.5], [5.7, 6.0], [7.0, 2.0]], [[-9.5, -10.0], [10.0, -5.0], [-6.4, -1.1]]] 
so why do this step back and forth !! plus we should work on the X not data